# Alternative/improvement on 'ignominously'

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm writing about a relationship that works out, despite a first date at a restaurant that was terrible.  I want a sentence like "It began quite **ignominiously** (at a terrible restaurant)," but I don't think '**ignominiously**' is really the best word for the sentiment that the restaurant choice was a poor start.

I've considered 'ominous' as a substitute, but think it's too strong.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: This is usually expressed: It began inauspiciously.

Comment: There's not enough context. Was the relationship ultimately a success, or a disaster? This may affect the choice of words to describe how the relationship began.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the relationship ***got off to a rough start*** or maybe ***started out on rocky ground***?

Answer (score 0):

"It began quite ingloriously..." -> Possibly expressing that while the end result is a success, it starts with things going wrong at the start?

Answer (score 0):

**aparente001** had it: *It began inauspiciously.*